# Add thousand separator s to all columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple numeric columns that need a thousand separator added to every column. Is there a simple way of doing this?

I have tried using `mutate_all` and `prettyNum(var, big.mark=",")` but I am an R newbie and can't figure out the syntax for just applying this across a whole dataframe. I have tried doing things like this:

```
    df <- df %>%
  mutate_all(prettyNum(var, big.mark = ","))
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutate_all` was superseded. You can use `across`, by the default it will apply the function to all columns, but you can also use the argument `.cols` to set a specific group of variables to apply.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~prettyNum(., big.mark = ",")))
```